# Converting docx to pdf via JODConverter and LibreOffice causes error

Tags: java, ms-office, libreoffice, pdf-conversion, jodconverter

I have 1000 .docx files that I want to convert to pdf so I have written a program to do this, but I can never get through all 1000 files before an error is thrown. I start a headless version of LibreOffice using `soffice --headless --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002;urp;"`. I am using LibreOffice 4.2.0.4 and JODConverter 2.2.2. This is my conversion code (prior to this I just iterate all the .docx files in a directory):

```java
try {
        File inputFile = new File(sourceFile);
        if (!inputFile.exists()) {
            return -1;
        }

        File outputFile = new File(destFile);
        OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(host_Str, 
            Integer.parseInt(port_Str));
        connection.connect();
        DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
        converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

        connection.disconnect();

        return 0;
    }

    catch (ConnectException e) {
        System.out.println("Openoffice listener exception!");
        return 1;
    }
```

I can always convert at least 50 files or so before an error is thrown; this is one of the errors I have had:

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: 
    conversion failed: could not save output document; OOo errorCode: 3088
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:142)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:120)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:104)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:74)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:70)
at previews.ConvertToPdfJOD.office2PDF(ConvertToPdfJOD.java:119)
at previews.ConvertToPdfJOD.beginConvert(ConvertToPdfJOD.java:91)
at previews.ConvertToPdfJOD.main(ConvertToPdfJOD.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Caused by: com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///C:/dev/testFiles/docx/newsletter_t3w7-2012.docx.pdf> failed: 0xc10
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:182)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:148)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:344)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:313)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:101)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:652)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.storeToURL(Unknown Source)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.storeDocument(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:156)
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:140)
... 12 more
```

Other error examples include:

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: 
    conversion failed: could not save output document

Caused by: com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException: [msci_uno bridge error] 
    UNO type of C++ exception unknown: "std.bad_alloc", RTTI-name=".?AVbad_alloc@std@@"!
```

and

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: 
    conversion failed: could not save output document; OOo errorCode: 283

Caused by: com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store 
    <file:///R:/document%20preview%20DY/speedTests/doc/cm9draftfinallist.doc.pdf> failed: 0x11b
```

and

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: 
    conversion failed: could not load input document
```

and

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: 
    conversion failed: could not save output document; OOo errorCode: 3088

Caused by: com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store 
    <file:///C:/dev/testFiles/docx/newsletter_t3w7-2012.docx.pdf> failed: 0xc10
```

In every situation (so far), I have been able to retry the conversion on the docx file where the error occurred and the conversion has been successful.

I have looked at similar questions on this site but most them are for situations where an error is thrown the first time a conversion is attempted, whereas in my case there are always some successful conversions before a failure. I have also tried using OpenOffice with the same results. I have tried googling error messages but to no avail.

My question is why are these errors occurring, and what can I do to convert all 1000 docx files? Also I am aware of [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) but I need to be able to convert .doc files as well which this does not support.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with PHP and using the python script to convert and I faced a problem similar to yours, I had errorCode 283 and SfxBaseModel::impl_store  failed: 0x11b.

I have an Apache server that runs with **apache** user and a regular user that runs LibreOffice service, let's say **theuser**, **theuser** is on **apache** group in order to write on tmp folders of my app. When I convert to pdf I create a folder (let's call it **thefolder**) to store the converted file (using mkdir function on PHP) I saw that **thefolder** hasn't group write permission and I test with other location from terminal (with **theuser** user) and it works, on **thefolder** I have errorCode 283, what I did is use umask function in PHP to change the permission for the creation of **thefolder**.

Summary: Check permissions on folder in wich you'll put the resulting file

Comment: I am not using any folders but a ByteStream instad, even with chmod 777 it displays the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem. What solved for me was running soffice as root:

```
soffice --headless --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002;urp;"
```